# Select the minimum value from a nested field in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the columns:

```
vehicle_trip_id, operator_id, waypoints.timestamp, waypoints.lat, waypoints.lon
```

where waypoints is a nested field. How can I find the number of unique vehicle trips for each trip start date and operator id?

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vehicle_trip_id) AS num_vehicle_trips, 
        operator_id, 
        MIN(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(w.timestamp))) AS date
FROM {}.{}.vehicle_trip, 
UNNEST(waypoints) as w
GROUP BY operator_id, w.timestamp
ORDER BY num_vehicle_trips
```

However, this is giving me the date of every waypoint, rather than only the earliest waypoint for each vehicle trip and operator.

Comment: Can share some sample source data and expected output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is **count number of trips from an operator by trip start date** you can do the following

```sql
WITH vehicle_trip_min_timestamp as
 (
   SELECT 
        vehicle_trip_id vehicle_trip_id,
        operator_id, 
        MIN(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(w.timestamp))) AS min_ts
FROM {}.{}.vehicle_trip, 
UNNEST(waypoints) as w
GROUP BY operator_id,vehicle_trip_id
   )
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vehicle_trip_id) AS num_vehicle_trips, 
        operator_id, 
        min_ts
FROM vehicle_trip_min_timestamp
GROUP BY operator_id,min_ts
ORDER BY num_vehicle_trips
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Much appreciated.